# Send Grid - Does anyone know how to pick a send grid template using its ID when using the api to send an email?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

**Send Grid - Does anyone know how to pick a send grid template using its ID when using the api to send an email?**

I've got this working for sending a subject, email address and body text but I want to select a template I made in send grid.

Is there any way to call a template in send grid by its ID?

*I'm using node js to call the send grid api using javascript.

Comment: Did you look at the Templates section in the documentation? https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the docs under "Templates" here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs

From their example using node js:

```
email.addFilter('templates', 'enable', 1);
email.addFilter('templates', 'template_id', '09c6ab89-9157-4710-8ca4-db7927c631d6');
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that today

Comment: I've added my code above - where do I add that addFilter to that bit of code?